# Select vector element based on condition in R

Tags: r

```
info <- c("1.8 Unspecified Hybrid", "Hatchback", "Automatic", "Grey", "40,186 km", "2019 (191)", "1 owner", "4 doors", "5 seats", "2023 March")
```

I have a vector as above. I want to select the element that contains "km" to retrn the character 40,186 km

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: `info[grepl("km",info)]`.

Comment: `grep('km', info, value = TRUE)`